# Update GUI in onCharacteristicRead() Android Java BLE

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am trying to update the GUI when a characteristic is found, however. when i attempt to do this with `txtlevel.setText(i);` The activity on the app does not update and when debugging the program cannot get past this point. I was wondering if there was an easy way to update the GUI whilst checking for characteristics in BLE. When debugging the value returned is `0` and should update the GUI. Here is the code for `onCharacteristicRead()`:

```
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                int i = characteristic.getValue()[0];
                Log.d("LEVEL ", Integer.toString(i));
                txtlevel.setText(i);
            }
        }
    };
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks again

Comment: A ResourceNotFoundException occurs when this is thrown into a try catch block, however this resource is defined in `onCreate()`  `txtlevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_level);`

Comment: You need to update the UI from the main thread. Bluetooth callbacks are usually run on Binder threads, so post the work to a Handler that uses the main looper and then update the text.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem thanks